# How to pass a Combobox value to BackgroundWorker without freezing the GUI C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, combobox, backgroundworker

I am trying to pass a combobox value to BackgroundWorker in C# Winform. I am using two ways of coding, the first one below:

```
public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            else
            {
                this.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
                {
                    Text = comboBox2.Text;
                    Text = comboBox3.Text;
                }));

                if (checkBox1.Checked == true) { ChkDatatoList(); }
                else { UnchkDatatoList(); }

                LoadDataToDGV();
                ManagingDataInDGV();
            }
        }
```

The above example throws me exception, and doesn't really work.

Another way of coding is:

```
 public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        else
        {
            this.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
            {
                Text = comboBox2.Text;
                Text = comboBox3.Text;

                if (checkBox1.Checked == true) { ChkDatatoList(); }
                else { UnchkDatatoList(); }

                LoadDataToDGV();
                ManagingDataInDGV();
            }));
        }
    }
```

Now the above code works, but it's freezing the GUI, which isn't really much useful to use the BackgroungWorker if that's the case.

So, is there a way to pass the combobox value to background worker without freezing the GUI?

Comment: Why are you using the DoWork event to update UI? That's incorrect. It's performed in a non-UI thread. Use BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm using DoWork, for all the calculations required. ProgressChanged for progress status and RunWorkerCompleted for all the final steps that needs to be done after the calculations are done. If you think your way can solve the problem could you please show it in a small example to better understand what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

There are two rules you must know:

1. All UI elements such as text boxes and drop downs are created in the **main** thread and should therefore *almost* always be accessed from the main thread.
2. Remember rule 1. really well. Anything you created in thread B should be used in thread B only.

Since all GUI is created in the main thread, anything blocking the main thread (like your loading logic) will block the GUI, which you have witnessed yourself.

The event `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` is executed on another, new thread, not the main thread. Therefore, the logic from your first code snipped breaks the first and foremost rule, you have used GUI elements outside of the main thread. You will often get cross thread operation exception because of that.

Your second code snipped does the opposite - everything is executed in the main thread, you don't want that either. What you really want is to:

- Execute the GUI logic in the main thread (also called GUI thread).
- Execute all the background loading code from another thread.

With all that being said, your code would have to look something like this:

```
public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Place loading logic here (i.e. load your data into a private variable)

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
        {
            // TODO: Update GUI here (i.e. bind the grid to the private variable you previously loaded
        }));
    }
}
```

And consider using the [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Read up more on how the background worker works and you will have a better understanding on how to use it.

The `this.Invoke` method allows you to execute code in the *main* thread while you are on another thread (which is the case with `DoWork` event). Hope you have some better understanding now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm using the combobox value in a method called "ChkDatatoList" or "UnchkDatatoList". So I tried to use your method but still doesn't work. Any more specific advice?

Comment: It depends on what `ChkDatatoList` do? You should store settings from check boxes, combo boxes and other UI elements in a variable and use the variable rather than directly call UI elements from worker thread. That way you are safe from cross thread exceptions.

Comment: I've been trying for hours to figure it out but still can't. I understood what you meant but still have no idea how to implement it successfully.So if I have a method which is used in the background worker. That method uses two comboboxes values. Could you please show or link a simple example on how to use these value inside the method and then use this method inside the backgroundWorker without freezing the GUI? Thanks.

Comment: I recommend reading some examples of how BW is used, e.g. [BackgroundWorker Class Sample for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)